# MongoDB 3.6.x change stream marshalling/unmarshalling in NodeJS driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB 3.6.2's change streams(with Mongo NodeJS driver 3.0.1) to try to implement resumeable streams of data to the browser.  So at some point in my code I am doing a JSON.stringify on the resume token that I get back during an update(ie the _id for the update from the change stream).  I send this across the wire to the front end app and then when there is a disconnect and subsequent reconnect, this information is sent back to the server to let it know where to resume from.  However, I can not seemingly simply supply this JSON object back to the driver to resume from as I get an invalid type for the resume token as a runtime error.

An example of what the stringify is resulting in:

> {"_data":"glpeTK8AAAABRmRfaWQAZFoygBEXtikxY6F/zgBaEAQkFlJHID5PgaLDUFQD2jMyBA=="}

The actual resume token appears to be a specialized buffer object in the form:

```
{
  _data: {
    buffer: Buffer(49),
    position = 49,
    sub_type = 0,
    _bsontype = "Binary"
  }
}
```

My problem is, of course, in getting the string back into an actual resume token.  The Buffer(49) itself seems to be getting converted into a base64 string which is then assigned to _data.  I am uncertain what the other fields are.  I have not been able to find much documentation on this sort of marshalling/unmarshalling of the tokens to handle resumptions of the streamed data to the client(given multiple node servers for scaling, simply keeping the token on the server is not really a good option, since that server may go down and the client tries to reconnect, so it having the token that relates to where it left off and the next server it connects to picking up from there is optimal).

In general it seems the resume tokens have been locked down hard from the developer, it contains valuable information that I could use (what collection we are on, timestamp for the update, etc), but none of this is made available to me(although it is apparently a feature they will be adding for 3.7).  Likewise I can't even get a resume token for the current moment in time for a given collection(very useful if I've read a collection in and haven't had any updates, but don't want to read it in fully again if I disconnect/reconnect just because no updates have occurred to the collection).  But hopefully some of these facilities will be getting added as Mongo realizes their usefulness.

I have tested successfully using the resume token's to resume a stream if there is no marshalling/unmarshalling involved (ie the token sits as an object on the server and is not converted to a wire-acceptable form).  But this is not very useful in a scaled environment.

Comment: Just to be clear, I do of course JSON.parse the incoming stringified resume token, although this just creates a JSON object that looks very much like the stringified string(_data field with the base64 string as it's value, nothing else).

Comment: Hey, I'm playing with the change stream and my resumeToken looks different and I'm not sure how to make use if it?
```
 { _data:
      Binary {
        _bsontype: 'Binary',
        sub_type: 0,
        position: 38,
        buffer: <Buffer 82 5a 5e 7f 3f 00 00 00 01 46 1e 5f 69 64 00 2b 24 00 5a 10 04 57 29 af c4 18 e2 4c 53 89 00 c1 52 57 83 18 3d 04> } }
```

Comment: My buffer looks pretty much like yours only different bytes of course since it is different collection names and time stamps.  I just summarized mine as Buffer(49) meaning it is a buffer of 49 bytes.  I believe that position seems to indicate the length of the buffer, though if so that is an odd name for the property.  In counting your bytes it is indeed 38 bytes.  Otherwise your object is exactly the same as mine.

Comment: If you supply that resumeToken to the resumeAfter option when starting up your new change stream, then you should see updates that have occurred after the update that the resumeToken is associated with.  So to test this you need to get the update with the resumeToken, then make more updates, then apply that resumeToken to resumeAfter option when you start up the change stream again, and you should see those latter updates come in.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else has this problem I thought I would post my current solution, though I still invite better solutions.

Through the magic of BSON, I simply serialize the resume token, convert that buffer to base64, and send that to the browser.  Then when the browser sends it back after a disconnect/reconnect, I simply make a buffer from the base64, and use bson to deserialize that buffer.  The resulting token works like a charm.

Ie, my marshalling of the update token looks like this code:

```
b64String = bson.serialize(resumeToken).toString('base64');
```

And, my unmarshalling of the base64 token sent after a disconnect/reconnect looks like this code:

```
token = bson.deserialize(Buffer.from(b64String, 'base64'));
```

Comment: Thanks you for this post. This makes a whole lot of sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can utilise MongoDB Extended JSON library: [npm module mongodb-extjson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-extjson) to stringify and parse the token.

For example:

```
const EJSON = require("mongodb-extjson");

resumeToken = EJSON.stringify(changeStreamDoc._id);
```

and to resume:

```
changeStream = collection.watch([], { resumeAfter: EJSON.parse(resumeToken) });
```

Tested on `mongodb-extjson` version 2.1.0 and MongoDB v3.6.3